# zoom and rotate image , option in iframe

Tags: javascript, html, iframe

i want to know zoom plus and zoom minus and rotate the image in iframe.

thanks  in advance;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to do a web search as Wade suggested until you run into a specific problem. One site you can look at is [here](http://www.javascriptkit.com/script/script2/imagezoom.shtml). This [one](http://randsco.com/index.php/2005/01/31/css_photo_caption_zoom) has eight different examples.